# How do I change the dimension of an image from 3D matrix to 2D matrix in python?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image:

```
labels = cv2.imread("/Users/vaibhavsaxena/Desktop/corn1 copy.png")
labels.shape
(1528, 1518, 3)
```

How do I change the shape to `(1528, 1518)` ?

I have tried:

```
labels = labels.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(3,-1)
```

That didnt give me the desired output.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third element in `labels.shape` is the number of channels. If you want to change the shape to `(1528, 1518)`, you could use `cv.cvtColor` and you will get a gray image.

Here is opencv documentation on cvtColor: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab

Comment: Got, it. Thanks. cv2.imread("/Users/vaibhavsaxena/Desktop/corn1 copy.png", 0)